# string manipulation error: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Tags: python

while running the code, I am getting an error.

```
import re

pattern="""
(?P<title>.*)
(-\ located\ in\ )
(?P<city>\w*)
( ,\ )
(P?<state>\w*)"""

for item in re.finditer(pattern,wiki, re.VERBOSE):
    print(item.groupdict())
```

Comment: You need to decode `wiki` to string: `wiki.decode('utf8')` (or whatever other encoding you are using)

Comment: convert `wiki` from `bytes` to `string` - or use prefix `b` in pattern to use `bytes` instead of `string` - `pattern = b"""..."""`